# Digital inputs problem

Tags: microcontroller, relay, opto-isolator, gpio

I'm designing a digital I/O module which isolated with optocouplers. I'm done with the outputs, but having a confusion about input side.

[image]

I will have some switches and sensors to read as inputs, but I don't know how to do the connections, can someone show me as a schematic?

Which pin should be GPIO pin for example?

Comment: Isnt this an open collector opto? See this example for interfacing https://i.stack.imgur.com/O77bb.png

Comment: subset of [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/450691/i-o-module-with-optocouplers)

Comment: Yes actually it is related to that question

Comment: You need to be very specific about the "sensors". What kind of signal are they providing?

Comment: They will be switches supplied by 24V DC.

Comment: I dont understand your question.Do you want to connect the opto inputs to MCU general-purpose input/output pins?

Comment: Yes, I want to read the inputs in my MCU, and I want to isolate it by using opto.

Comment: Tip: Ground symbols should point down towards the ground. (The symbol represents parallel metal plates buried in earth.) In your circuit you could use one ground symbol on each side with vertical connections to each of the resistors or pins.

Comment: You already posted this at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/450691/i-o-module-with-optocouplers **DO NOT REPOST**

Answer (score 0):

The collector outputs will each need a pull-up resistor to Vdd, your CPU logic voltage, so that these pins may go "high". Other than that, it should work. The resistance value chosen (along with the capacitance of each line) determines how fast the output goes high. If speed isn't an issue, 10kΩ should work. But for fast speeds, much lower values will be better, and this means the current rating of the transistors inside the opto needs to be taken into consideration.

Edit: The [STM32F072C8T6](https://datasheet.octopart.com/STM32F072C8T6-STMicroelectronics-datasheet-61689933.pdf) has a supply voltage of 3.3v nominal. Bypass caps must be installed across Vdd/Vss pins. Make sure `BOOT0`, `VBAT`, and `NRST` lines are handled correctly according to the datasheet.

The [TLP280-4](https://datasheet.octopart.com/TLP280-4%28GB-TP%2CJ%2CF-Toshiba-datasheet-13727484.pdf) LEDs can be driven to 50mA: 24v/50mA = 480Ω minimum input resistance. Output transistor limit is also 50mA: 3.3v/50mA = 66Ω minimum pull-up. Smaller resistances will be faster, if speed is a concern.

Comment: So is this schematic true according to your opinion? https://ibb.co/BsPDW16  this is the link for schematic. Thank you

Comment: Looks ok to me, you'll have to try it. :)

Comment: thank you so much @rdtsc :)